# Confusion with figuring out voltage regulator maximum input voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator

I will use [this](https://www.ariat-tech.com/datasheet/8d/SI-3010LLSL.pdf) 12V voltage regulator which in my case marked as MC7812ABT and TO−220 package. And I want to use it for a 12V 16mA load where it will regulate 24V supply to 12V. In the datasheet there is a section which confuses me:

[image]

There is 19V, 27V and 30V ect. mentioned. In my case the output will be 12V, can the input voltage be 24V?

Comment: Yes, you can use it Vin max = 35V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For maximum input, refer to the "Maximum Ratings" section. In your case, as you have a 12 V part (`MC7812ABT`), V<sub>I-max</sub>=35 V.
[image]

The electrical characteristics table specifies behaviour under certain conditions. In this case, the Output Voltage is specified to be in the range 12 V (+-0.5 V) for V<sub>I</sub> = [14.8..27] V. It does not specify the output for e.g. V<sub>I</sub>=V<sub>I-max</sub> and you'd have to measure that yourself.

[image]

**Note** that your screenshot refers to another part, not `MC7812ABT` as you said you are using.

#### Update:

Your part is a `12 V` part, which can be found in the table of all parts (ordering information). This is why you look at the "5.0 - 18 V" maximum rating, not the "24 V" one. Which tells you `35 V` is the maximum.
[image]

The `221A` is your case code. Here, I'm a bit lost too why they call it 221AB sometimes and sometimes 221A. Luckily in this case though, there is no difference between the cases, regarding the max input voltage.

[image]

Comment: What is 221A? And in my screenshot MC7812AB is the closest thing in the datasheet to MC7812ABT. I dont understand the method to conclude what makes the result as 35V in my case. Could you explain it more explicitly?

Comment: Sure - pleae see my updated answer. Your screenshot shows the table for `MC7812B`, not `MC7812AB`, but the difference is marginal.